# Page header and Page footer items in MS Report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer2008

I have added Page Header from Report>>Page Header menu.  Then I added a textbox to my page header.  I donot know how to display the value from a variable to this text box.

Please advise.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

You can right click in the box and select “Create Placeholder” from the context menu. You can then set the value of that placeholder to any variable in your report. You can put more than one place holder in a text box so you example you could have a big text box that tells you the date range of a report

Comment: I right clicked the text box but did not find anything like Create Place holder.

Comment: @user415037 Did you click in the text box first to edit it's text? Its from that context menu that you will find the "Create Placeholder" option you need